# Why symbol for 1/4 in title "Bijlage"?

Tags: symbols, appendices

I added an appendix to my document using the standard command.
I have some chapters and at the end of my file, I have two appendices: "Bijlage a Bronvermelding" and "Bijlage b Categorie-Onderwerp combinaties".
I used following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
% Packages I am going to use
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% Comand ddefinitions
\newcommand*\voordeel{\item[+]}
\newcommand*\nadeel{\item[-]}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Before the appendices}
Some text \ldots
\appendix % to indicate the start of the appendices section
\chapter{Bronvermelding}
Some text for appendix B.
\chapter{Categorie-Onderwerp combinaties}
Here the text of appendix b.
\end{document}
```

When I execute this code, and all other code, I get "B¼lage" instead of "Bijlage". In the Table Of contents, there's only the letters a and b, so that's no problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think it could be an encoding issue. Do you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, for example, and save your files as utf8? Rather: do you save your file *in the same encoding expected*? We should see your preamble to determine what is expected and only you can see how it is saved

Comment: Furthermore check your font encoding. Do you use the appropriate encoding for your language (`T1` I guess)?

Comment: You must be using a font in which `ij' is mapped to a single glyph.... which font are you using?

Comment: @JPi I think the standard one. This is my preamble:
```\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
% Packages I am going to use
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Comand ddefinitions
\newcommand*\voordeel{\item[+]}
\newcommand*\nadeel{\item[-]}```

Comment: @moriambar Yes I save it correctly. See my earlier comment for the preamble.
@texnician Yes, I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` :)

Comment: You should remove everything that doesn't cause a problem. For example, we don't have the pdf you're including and unless that's important, you should remove it. When I compile your code without the `\includepdf`, I don't see any problems. Do you see an issue when you compile that document?

Comment: @th. Yes, when I execute the example code, I get the problem...

Comment: compiles fine for me, also.....

Comment: *Do you see the problem when you omit the included PDF, which we don't have?* Please amend your example, if so. If code we can compile gives correct output and the same code gives you incorrect output, create a new directory and a blank `.tex` file. Copy the (amended) code from here into the empty document. Compile. Do you still see the problem? If so, post the .log file for that example.

Comment: @cfr I still saw the issue, but the log file was over 450 lines!
@JPi @cfr @moriambar @texnician @th. To everyone: I found a solution: I removed the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` from my pre-amble.
Is this line required? What does it especially do?

Comment: For Dutch, yes, you want `T1` if you are using pdfTeX. It supports accented characters properly, which looks better and supports searching the PDF etc.

Comment: You can post your log on a pastebin site, if necessary. However, first, try to minimise the code by removing things and seeing if you still get the problem. Hopefully, you'll get a short enough log to post here. There is something very seriously wrong if you are getting that output and ignoring the problem won't make it go away ;).